# Optimal way to refresh specific rows in a ListView when using a MatrixCursor

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh, matrixcursor

I have a `ListView` with a custom `CursorAdapter` feed from a `MatrixCursor`. Each row in the `ListView` has an image that is loaded asynchronously, and when the image loading completes, I would like to signal the adapter to redraw the row in question. I do something similar already with data from a `ContentProvider` where I call `getContentResolver().notifyChange` to redraw a specific row. For a `MatrixCursor`, I can call `notifyDataSetChanged`, but that's not optimal, as it refreshes every row.

So my question is, what's the best way to go about redrawing specific rows in a `ListView` from a temporary source? Is there a way to set up "temporary" `ContentUri`s, or some way to request that the adapter only invalidate specific rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the same effect using `setNotificationUri` on `MatrixCursor` with an arbitrary URI, then using `getContentResolver.notifyChange()` to signal a redraw. While this works for me, I'd be curious to know whether this is an advised way of requesting redraw of specific items.